# Why can't I use JPA, database and primefaces together?

Tags: java, database, jpa, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a User class, whitch is a database `@Entity` for JPA.

I have a UserServiceImpl class, which have this `getAllUser()` method (from the Exception below: UserServiceImpl.java:16=the second row):

```
public UserServiceImpl(){
    em = EMService.getEntityManager();
}
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> getAllUser() {
    String jpql = "SELECT u FROM User u";
    Query q = em.createQuery(jpql);
    List<User> users = (List<User>) q.getSingleResult();
    return users;
}
```

I have a UserBean class, whitch is managed bean in the `faces-config.xml` for the primefaces. And there will be the Exception (UserBean.java:19=5th row):

```
private List<User> users;
private User selectedUser;
private UserServiceImpl userService;
public UserBean() {
    userService = new UserServiceImpl();
    users = userService.getAllUser();
}
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
```

I think, the problem is that a managed bean can't use another classes. This is the Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
at hu.pte.admin.services.EMService.getEntityManager(EMService.java:12)
at hu.pte.admin.services.usersmodul.UserServiceImpl.<init>(UserServiceImpl.java:16)
at hu.pte.admin.managedbeans.UserBean.<init>(UserBean.java:19)
```

This is the method of the EMService class (the second row is the wrong = EMService.java:12):

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Admin");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    return em;
}
```

And this is the users.xhtml (detail), where i want to use the managed bean (userBean) in the primefaces code:

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userBean.users}" paginator="true" rows="10"
        selection="#{userBean.selectedUser}" selectionMode="single" 
        onRowSelectUpdate="display" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
        <f:facet name="header">The Users</f:facet>

        <p:column sortBy="#{user.id}" filterBy="#{user.id}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="ID" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
        </p:column>
```

The persistance.xml has the code to connect to my database. Please help me, i can't find any sample in the internet, whitch are use JPA and PrimeFaces together like this! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The exception clearly shows you:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
```

There is no class definition found for `javax.persistence.Persistence` class. I'm assuming you're running a Java SE SDK. I suggest downloading and running the [Java EE 6 SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) which inlcudes the `Persistence` API.

Comment: yes, i installed, and a got the same Exception :) i told, the problem is in the UserBean's constructor, the declaration.

Comment: Well JEE is not needed, just "persistence-api.jar". Why download XXX Mb when 110Kb will do? Get geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec/1.0/

Comment: @victorio, there's nothing wrong with your `UserBean` constructor. You just need the jar containing the Persistence API as @DataNucleus suggested. Just deploy the jar in your web server library folder.

Comment: oh!! something works! now i have this exception: 
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: hu.pte.admin.managedbeans.UserBean.

Comment: New exception = new question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the NoClassDefFoundError, there is also a problem in your `getAllUsers` method:

```
List<User> users = (List<User>) q.getSingleResult();
```

Calling `getSingleResult` will return a single User entity if the query result is unique, otherwise it will throw an exception. To retrieve a list of users you need to call `getResultList` instead.

Comment: Thanks!! You are right! I deployed the geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar in my web server library folder, and now I have a new Exception: `com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: hu.pte.admin.managedbeans.UserBean.` Could you help me with this?

Comment: @victorio: Please create a new question and include the full stacktrace.